# drawViewHierarchyInRect not working

Tags: ios

I have a map view, which can display a SVG map.

I used to use `renderInContext` to get the UIImage, however its performance is not ideal and I heard iOS 7 has new APIs to do such things, which is `drawViewHierarchyInRect`

Now I want to turn this map view into UIImage or a screenshot as UIView by `drawViewHierarchyInRect`
However,

If I use drawViewHierarchyInRect, no valid UIImage I can get neither, I suspect they are the same reason

The code for snapshotView,

PS: for performance, I don't add _mapView into any views

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_mapView.bounds.size, _mapView.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //    [mapView.layer renderInContext:context];
    [_mapView drawViewHierarchyInRect:_mapView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.thumbImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self addSubview:self.thumbImageView];
}
```